# What app places a lower-case 'd' icon in the menu bar?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation

Does anyone recognize this app which has an icon "d"?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's [gfxCardStatus](http://gfx.io) in discrete graphics mode.

> **what the menu bar icons mean:**
>
> i — you're using the integrated GPU.
> d — you're using the higher-powered discrete GPU.

Comment: It's a great application for stopping other applications that try to use the discrete GPU but don't really need it from doing so (and thus degrading your battery life). Coda 2 was the worst offender on my machine, though they say they've fixed it in the most recent release. But I also like to force the integrated GPU when playing Civilization V; the FPS drops, but not to an unplayable level, and I get more battery life and time to play (and less heat and fan noise!).

Answer (score 3):

It is [gfxCardStatus](http://gfx.io). You can use it to view and change the graphics mode on your machine.